# Как сделать бэкап БД, WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть доступ в админ панель, знаю пароль от базы данных, от FTP.
Нет доступа к плагинам, не знаю пароль от хостинга. Как можно в таком случае сделать бэкап БД?

Comment: *"от FTP"* а что мешает залить по FTP скрипт, который сдампит базу?

Comment: А какой скрипт? Подскажите, пожалуйста. :(

Comment: Да какой угодно, "скрипт для дампа базы mysql" в любом поисковике. Хоть phpmyadmin заливайте и делайте что хотите, или любой другой менеджер БД, раз доступ на FTP есть.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть доступ по фтп, залейте [Sypex Dumper](https://sypex.net/ru/) и создайте дамп через него. Логин и пароль для базы возьмите в wp-config.php

Локально проделайте ту же процедуру, но только с импортом

Answer (score 0):

Плагин Duplicator, например: [Ссылка](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)
Скачайте zip плагина на локальный диск, разверните, залейте папку в /wp-content/plugins

Comment: "нет доступа к плагинам" - не подойдет же.

Comment: Что значит - нет доступа к плагинам? И есть доступ как админке. Этот как?

Comment: То, что аккаунт в админке ограничен.
Я имею доступ только к плагинам, которые выведены в меню админки.
Кстати, Duplicator там установлен но выдает вот такую ошибку https://yadi.sk/i/Rg0ByZcFyPE8B .

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждения. С ними можно продолжить, если сайт не очень большой. Но лучше на предыдущем экране отменить копирование файлов и скопировать только базу

Comment: То есть БД полностью скопируется?

Comment: Разумеется. Я так сайты переношу регулярно с одного сервера на другой.